# If a comment is too long, is it OK to post it as an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, comments-as-answers

Bob has a comment on a question.  However, Bob's comment is too long to fit in the comment box.  Does that make it OK for Bob to paste his comment into the answer box?  If not, what should Bob do instead?

<sub>(Before you downvote me into oblivion.... no, I don't plan to do this.  This is intended as a reference question, for others who want to know why doing this isn't OK.  I ran across someone who used "my comment is too long to fit into the comment box" as a justification for posting their comment as an answer, and when I went searching, I realized I couldn't find an existing question here to point them to, to explain the policy on this.  Since this isn't the first time I've seen this happen, I thought it would be valuable to have a single reference we can point new users to, to explain this aspect of how the site works.)</sub>

Comment: If it's not an answer then it is a "no". Just split to several comments.

Comment: It might depend on the culture of a particular site (board?) and Bob's judgement. "I can't answer your question but here is a useful illustration..." On some math sites one can preview the result of LaTeX code in an answer but in a comment one must submit, Rush to correct during the edit window or delete and resubmit ( if one remembered to save in a file before submitting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  The only content that should ever be posted as an answer is an answer to the question.  There is no relationship between answers, except as they relate to the question, so posting a comment in an answer will only be confusing, unless you also quote the original answer extensively.

The system doesn't support this usage, and has moderation and flagging tools to remove such content specifically because some people abuse the system this way.

Don't do it.

> Bob's comment is too long to fit in the comment box.

I think Bob may need to re-evaluate his life choices, or at least consider more carefully what he hopes to accomplish with his comment.

If there is too much wrong with the answer, or too much that needs to be clarified, then you may be better served by either downvoting it, or editing it.

If you agree with portions, but then want to add to it, consider editing it, or adding your own answer which says, "[otheranswer] is great, and if we continue with that solution we find that the following improvements can be made..."

If there's one or two points that are wrong or could be clarified, but conveying the fix or problem will take a Whole Lot Of Words, then you should probably submit another answer that is a complete answer that would stand alone even if the other answer were deleted.  Add a comment to their answer, "Your answer has a problem, pleas see my answer to understand it." In this way you provide a correct answer, and if the other person wants to understand the issue they can read your answer. They may choose to delete their answer, or fix it, or they may prove you wrong with more explanation in their answer.

Any other reason to leave a comment probably shouldn't even be a comment, nevermind an answer. Comments are meant to be clarifiers.  Too much text gets in the way of that.

However if you can't control the impulse to send a wall of text, split the comment across several comments.  This will convey the information you want without running afoul of the answer system.

Answer (score 6):

No, if Bob posts his comment as an answer, and it is clearly a comment, then surely Alice will flag his answer as "not an answer", and in short order Charlie, Delta, the letter E, and the rest of the alphabet will vote to delete. If Bob posts too many poor answers or gets too many answers deleted, the consequence could be that he'll be limited to a certain number of answers per day, or week, or even banned from posting answers at all.

As Shadow Wizard mentioned, one option is to split the intended message in multiple comments. I would advise optimizing for brevity. Another option is to remain silent. Sometimes I reach for the comment box only to decide that a comment is not really worth it.

If Bob does not have the reputation to post comments yet, then he should wait until he can. We've all been there. It's annoying but overall it is better for the health of the site as it cuts down on spam or pointless comments.